# Converting ASCII encoded characters inside string in Python

Tags: python, json, email, ascii

I am using the IMapLib library to read emails from my mailserver. The emails contain JSON encoded messages which my program should interpret.

Mail code:

```
tmp, data = imap.search(None, "UNSEEN")
emails = []

for num in data[0].split():
    tmp, data = imap.fetch(num, "(BODY[TEXT])")
    # Only append the email body
    emails.append(str(data[0][1]))
```

The strings I get from imaplib however contain some special characters. I have figured out that the =xx looks like the ASCII encoded version of the 'special' characters. How could I convert a string containing such characters to a 'regular' Python string or am I perhaps missing an option in the imaplib code which is encoding the strings incorrectly?

An example string I get:

> b'This is a message in Mime Format.  If you see this, your mail reader does not support this format.\r\n\r\n--=_8e336d0902b13eaec4e7906847c21a6d\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n=0A=0A=0A=0A  =0A    =0A    =0A  =0A  =0A    =0A      JSON{"arrival":"03.03.21","departure":"07.03.21","email":"test=\r\n=2Etest@gmail.com","apartment":"app","ov=\r\nerride":0}JSON    =0A  =0A=0A\r\n--=_8e336d0902b13eaec4e7906847c21a6d\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n=0A=0A=0A=0A  =0A    <meta charset=3D"utf-8"=20=\r\n/>=0A    <meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type"  content=3D"text/html charset=\r\n=3DUTF-8" />=0A  =0A  =0A
>
> =0A      JSON{"arrival":"03.03.21","departure":"07.03.21","email":"test=\r\n=2Etest@gmail.com","apartment":"app","ov=\r\nerride":0}JSON
>
> =0A  =0A=0A\r\n--=_8e336d0902b13eaec4e7906847c21a6d--\r\n'

I was initially just removing all '\n', '\r' and '=' but today I received this email/string and my code incorrectly interpreted "test=\r\n=2Etest@gmail.com" as "test2Etest@gmail.com" instead of "test.test@gmail.com"

Comment: As said @Rivers, you may try to use imap_tools lib. In fact you do not need quopri.decodestring for parse email - see imap_tools message.py src. Regards, imap_tools author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dealing with the encoding scheme named "quoted printable" (more details in RFC 2045,section 6.7).

You have at least two options:

1. You could use the Python module `quopri`
2. You could parse your email with the parser of the Python `email` module (`email.parser`).

But if your goal is to easily get the email content, it would be easier to use the modules `imap_tools` or `IMAPClient`.

Some example code from their documentations:

imap_tools (https://pypi.org/project/imap-tools/):

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, AND

# get list of email subjects from INBOX folder
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'pwd') as mailbox:
    subjects = [msg.subject for msg in mailbox.fetch()]

# get list of email subjects from INBOX folder - equivalent verbose version
mailbox = MailBox('imap.mail.com')
mailbox.login('test@mail.com', 'pwd', initial_folder='INBOX')  # or mailbox.folder.set instead 3d arg
subjects = [msg.subject for msg in mailbox.fetch(AND(all=True))]
mailbox.logout()
```

IMAPClient (https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/):

```
from imapclient import IMAPClient
server = IMAPClient('imap.mailserver.com', use_uid=True)
server.login('someuser', 'somepassword')

select_info = server.select_folder('INBOX')
print('%d messages in INBOX' % select_info[b'EXISTS'])
#34 messages in INBOX

messages = server.search(['FROM', 'best-friend@domain.com'])
print("%d messages from our best friend" % len(messages))
#5 messages from our best friend

for msgid, data in server.fetch(messages, ['ENVELOPE']).items():
    envelope = data[b'ENVELOPE']
```

Answer (score 3):

You have hint relating encoding in your message, namely:

*Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable*

which explains `=`s in your text. You might use [quopri](https://docs.python.org/3/library/quopri.html) built-in module for dealing with it, following way:

```
import quopri
message = b'test=\r\n=2Etest@gmail.com'
decoded = quopri.decodestring(message)
print(decoded)
```

output:

```
b'test.test@gmail.com'
```

Note that `quopri.decodestring` return `bytes`, so you would have to make correct `.decode` if you must have text, if `utf-8` is used it will be:

```
decoded = quopri.decodestring(message).decode('utf-8')
```